# avoid normal mouse-cursor movement on pressing enter in textarea

Tags: textarea, enter, mouse-cursor

hi in my webpage i am saving textarea contents on pressing enter button . it is saving but what happens is mouse-cursor moves to next line . it always saves with a newline character . i just want to avoid the mouse-cursor moving to next line and just save it . for saving it i use event.keycode kind of stuff for the textarea and then save it

```
$('.text_desc_cls').keyup(function(event){save_text_val(event,this.id);});

function save_text_val(event,this_id){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
    req_id = '#'+this_id;
    textarea_val = $(req_id).val();
    $.post("./funcs.php?func=save_int_text_val",{textarea_val:textarea_val},function(data){
        alert('done');
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to grab the value on keydown - that will give you the value without the latest entry. It will show the newline in the textarea, so if you need that removed, you could switch to keyup rather than keydown and do a replace like so:

$(req_id).val($(req_id).val().replace(/\n/,''));

Comment: thanks a lot jack . both works good . according to you which is better?

Comment: It depends on what happens to the page afterwards. If you clear out the form after submission, the first is fine. However, if the text remains in the textarea after you post, then you'd want to replace the newline so that the user can see that the newline was not entered.